# What do all the various icons mean?

Tags: x-rebirth

There are tons of icons scattered all over the stations.  What does each of the icon represent?  I already recognize a few, such as the one for docking and for combat missions, but most of the others elude me.

Answer (score 1):

Section 2.7 of [the manual](http://cdn4.steampowered.com/Manuals/2870/X_Rebirth_Manual_English.pdf) goes over *some* of the icons you'll encounter.

Comment: that one only gives the list of icons where you can land at.  I'm looking for a more comprehensive list.

Comment: Tbh, I think X rebirth is meant to be explored, not learned via manual. Obviously, this will be needed when you get to endgame content, but I feel the game really wants you to just fly around and find stuff on your own. And to be honest, I like it that way.